# Perl mysql - importing csv file

Tags: mysql, perl, csv

I have an CSV file that I'm trying to import, without success. The integers in the file will not import, they all become zero's.

Here is the csv file.

```
RankOrderBy,EmployeeID,RankSurnameInitial,MustersAttended,BrigadeMusters,Brigade12MonthIncidents,Incidents Attended,Muster Pct,Incident Pct,OIC,Driver,Crew,OwnTransport,Total At Incident,At Station,Total Other,Incidents On Leave,Incidents Absent,Total Incident Tasks
5,900872,"SFF xxxxx, R J",32,48,241,74,0.6666667,0.30705394,0,24,27,0,51,23,23,62,105,241
19,904308,"OS-FF xxxxx, P H",38,48,241,123,0.7916667,0.51037344,9,12,30,1,52,71,71,0,118,241
4,904565,"SO xxxxxx, G R",48,48,241,190,1,0.78838174,31,7,33,0,71,119,119,0,51,241
3,905042,"SSO xxxxx, G W",40,48,241,130,0.8333333,0.53941909,49,5,12,2,68,62,62,2,109,241
5,905045,"SFF xxxxx, J G",41,48,241,175,0.8541667,0.72614108,2,100,34,0,136,39,39,13,53,241
5,905053,"SFF xxxxx, E J",43,48,241,118,0.8958333,0.48962656,9,1,54,0,64,54,54,0,123,241
5,905074,"SFF xxxxxx, D M",25,48,241,116,0.5208333,0.4813278,4,9,28,1,42,74,74,0,125,241
4,905088,"SO Sarcich, G",41,48,241,122,0.8541667,0.50622407,26,28,16,2,72,50,50,22,97,241
7,905089,"FF xxxxx, B A",33,48,241,42,0.6875,0.17427386,1,0,16,2,19,23,23,0,199,241
4,905096,"SO xxxxxx, S J",40,48,241,144,0.8333333,0.59751037,36,10,31,8,85,59,59,0,97,241
19,905132,"OS-FF xxxxx, V L",25,48,241,14,0.5208333,0.05809129,1,1,4,0,6,8,8,57,170,241
15,905188,"OS-SSO xxxxx, I J",32,48,241,74,0.6666667,0.30705394,15,4,3,0,22,52,52,0,167,241
19,907999,"OS-FF xxxxx, G J",26,48,241,71,0.5416667,0.29460581,3,20,8,0,31,40,40,1,169,241
6,909727,"QFF xxxxx, S M",31,48,241,71,0.6458333,0.29460581,0,0,58,0,58,13,13,0,170,241
20,909799,"OS-RFF xxxxxx, D  ",32,42,209,91,0.7619048,0.4354067,4,3,17,1,25,66,66,26,92,241
7,909991,"FF xxxxx, B T",25,48,241,53,0.5208333,0.21991701,0,0,15,2,17,36,36,0,188,241
5,910323,"SFF xxxx, S F",47,48,241,117,0.9791667,0.48547718,1,31,54,0,86,31,31,0,124,241
6,911345,"QFF xxxxx, D",39,48,241,129,0.8125,0.53526971,6,2,45,4,57,72,72,16,96,241
5,912197,"SFF xxxxx, M D",46,48,241,212,0.9583333,0.87966805,12,56,69,2,139,73,73,0,29,241
1,930928,"CFO xxxxx, J E",44,48,241,150,0.9166667,0.62240664,24,1,5,3,33,117,117,0,91,241
2,933456,"DCFO xxxxxx, A C",43,48,241,196,0.8958333,0.81327801,137,8,3,2,150,46,46,3,42,241
6,934986,"QFF xxxxxxx, T P",26,48,241,47,0.5416667,0.19502075,0,8,6,1,15,32,32,0,194,241
6,936929,"QFF xxxxxx, S T",30,48,241,63,0.625,0.26141079,0,2,33,1,36,27,27,14,164,241
6,937215,"QFF xxxxx, K S",37,48,241,44,0.7708333,0.18257261,0,7,22,0,29,15,15,9,188,241
6,938180,"QFF xxxxx, S J",40,48,241,125,0.8333333,0.5186722,2,23,24,0,49,76,76,0,116,241
7,942978,"FF xxxxx, K",43,48,241,111,0.8958333,0.46058091,0,0,94,0,94,17,17,0,130,241
20,943016,"OS-RFF xxxxx, S M",41,48,241,115,0.8541667,0.47717842,8,24,17,4,53,62,62,1,125,241
7,992884,"FF xxxxx, A M",28,48,78,38,0.5833333,0.48717949,0,0,22,0,22,16,16,0,203,241
7,993131,"FF xxxxx, R W",43,44,78,134,0.9772728,1.71794872,1,0,67,0,68,66,66,0,80,241
7,993279,"FF xxxxx, J R",31,39,42,78,0.7948718,1.85714286,0,0,36,0,36,42,42,1,117,241
7,993289,"FF xxxxx, C P",25,37,42,17,0.6756757,0.4047619,0,0,11,0,11,6,6,0,169,241
7,993327,"FF xxxxx, N",31,34,42,93,0.9117647,2.21428571,1,0,70,1,72,21,21,0,82,241
99,993941,"xxxxx, B A",7,8,38,0,0.875,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38,241
```

Here is my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

my $query="";
my $filename = "./muster.csv";

open(ACCESS_INFO, "<./access.DB") || die "Can't access login credentials";

my $database = <ACCESS_INFO>;
my $host = <ACCESS_INFO>;
my $userid = <ACCESS_INFO>;
my $passwd = <ACCESS_INFO>;

chomp ($database, $host, $userid, $passwd);

close(ACCESS_INFO);

my $connectioninfo="DBI:mysql:$database:$host";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($connectioninfo, $userid, $passwd, {mysql_enable_utf16 => 1} );

my $sth  = $dbh->prepare("DROP TABLE `tbl.test`");

$sth->execute;

my $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl.test` (`RankOrderBy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `EmployeeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `RankSurnameInitial` text, "
        . "`MustersAttended` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `BrigadeMusters` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `Brigade12MonthIncidents` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `IncidentsAttended` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, "
        . " `MusterPct` double DEFAULT NULL, `IncidentPct` double DEFAULT NULL, `OIC` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `Driver` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `Crew` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, "
        . "`OwnTransport` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `TotalAtIncident` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `AtStation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `TotalOther` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, "
        . "`IncidentsOnLeave` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `IncidentsAbsent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `TotalIncidentTasks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL)";

my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth1->execute;

$query = q{LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/pi/Documents/NZFS/book1.csv'
                INTO TABLE `tbl.test`
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                        ENCLOSED BY '"'
                        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                        IGNORE 1 LINES (
                                        RankOrderBy,
                                        EmployeeID,
                                        RankSurnameInitial,
                                        MustersAttended,
                                        BrigadeMusters,
                                        Brigade12MonthIncidents,
                                        IncidentsAttended,
                                        MusterPct,
                                        IncidentPct,
                                        OIC,
                                        Driver,
                                        Crew,
                                        OwnTransport,
                                        TotalAtIncident,
                                        AtStation,
                                        TotalOther,
                                        IncidentsOnLeave,
                                        IncidentsAbsent,
                                        TotalIncidentTasks
                                        )
        };


my $sqlQuery = $dbh->prepare($query);

#$sqlQuery->trace(2);

my $rv = $sqlQuery->execute();

$dbh->disconnect();

exit;
```

Here are the results viewed in MYSQL Workbench

[Results from MySQL workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ6L9.png)

So a couple of things happening.
1. the numbers in the csv file are not being entered into the table, they are ending up as zero's
2. the LOAD DATA INFILE statement is not taking into account the ENCLOSED BY '"' to account for the name filed that also has a comer in it.
3. You will see in the CSV file there are no spaces between the letters ie; SFF, this displays in the table as S F F for some reason, probably part of the issues above.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks

Comment: When fields are enclosed by `"`, the import expects all fields to be enclosed by this `"`.

Comment: Why use Perl for this at all? It seems like you're adding an unnecessary extra layer to the problem.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file book1.csv? If this is on a unixlike system, what is the output from `file book1.csv`?

Comment: The extra spaces could indicate that you are trying to load a ucs2 or utf16 file which mysql states that [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) cannot handle. You may want to ensure the csv file is encoded using ascii or utf8.

Comment: Thanks to those that provided helpful assistance. The issue is encoding, the file is utf16, once converted to utf8 it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are whole numbers and their negative opposites. Therefore, these numbers can never be integers:

- fractions
- decimals
- percents

Try changing the column types to FLOAT or DECIMAL instead of INT.